# Why can't all existential binders be replaced by unique constants during skolemization?

Tags: logic, proof, theorem-proving, type-theory

When using skolemization to replace existentially quantified variables in an expression, any existential bound at the top level can be replaced by a new globally unique constant, however if the existential is under a universal quantification it cannot be replaced by a constant. It must be replaced instead by a new globally unique predicate symbol which is applied to all the universally quantified variables in scope.

I don't understand why this must be so, since the uniqueness of the new predicate symbol must surely prevent it from unifying with any other object but itself.

Comment: This question does not belong here, consider moving it to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: It probably is better suited to the math stack exchange, but skolemization is directly software related for theorem provers and type checkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each step in Skolemization preserves the satisfiability of the formula. If all existentially-bound variables are replaced by constants instead of functions, the modified formula may be unsatisfiable even if the original formula was satisfiable.

Consider the formula
[image: \forall x \exists y. P(x,y)], where `P` is a first-order formula with free variables `x` and `y`. If you simply replace `y` with a new constant `c`, the resulting formula [image: \forall x. P(x,c)] is logically stronger, as `y` is allowed to depend on `x`, but `c` is not.

In other words, Skolemization relies on the (second-order) logical equivalence [image: \forall x \exists y P(x,y) \iff \exists f \forall x P(x,f(x))], and that [image: \forall x. P(x,f(x))] is satisfiable iff [image: \exists f \forall x.P(x,f(x))] is. Your suggestion breaks down because [image: \exists c \forall x.P(x,c)] is not equivalent to [image: \forall x \exists y. P(x,y)].

For a specific counter-example, suppose that `P` encodes the following:

- the axioms of group theory with operation `*` and identity `1`,
- the group has order at least 2: [image: \exists a \exists b. a \not = b] , and
- `y` is the inverse of `x`: `x*y = 1`.

Then [image: \forall x \exists y. P(x,y)] is satisfiable, since it says "every element of the group has an inverse." But [image: \forall x. P(x,c)] is not satisfiable, since it says "the element `c` is the inverse to every group element."